# Would photons trapped in a back hole have orbital angular momentum?

Tags: black-holes, photons

In a black hole radiation is trapped, it can’t escape. Its trajectories we bent by the curved spacetime.

So photon would perform at least  a partial rotation about the black hole.

Would this introduce orbital angular momentum of the photon about the black hole position?

Can I use:

$$ \mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p},$$ with $E=pc$?

Comment: it seems the answer is yes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere#Spherical_photon_orbits_around_a_Kerr_black_hole  this also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere#Spherical_photon_orbits_around_a_Kerr_black_hole

Comment: No, you cannot use $\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$ because it is expression for flat 3D space. Near black hole you must use general covariant objects.

Comment: @annav, that gives me $r$, can I use $E/c$ as $p$?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5429  , it is not that simple, even in special relativity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum

Comment: If someone makes that in an answer with a bit more words I'll accept it